# Cannot set variable in class equal to a function

Tags: php, class, variables, object

I started today with learning object oriented PHP programming and I am struggling with the following problem:

**I can set a variable equal to for example 10:**

```
class exampleClass {
   private $number = 10;
}
```

**But I cannot set it equal to a function which returns 10:**

```
class exampleClass {
   private $number = exampleFunction();
}
```

Comment: If it requires the use of a function, initialize the variable in the constructor function of the class.

Comment: No, you cannot. Functions need to be evaluated, and that does not happen when class is parsed. If you want to do this, use initialize method for that, or a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set class properties directly as expressions:

Invalid:

```
class Test {
    protected $blah = 1 + 1;
}
```

Instead set it in the class construct:

```
class Test {
    protected $blah;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->blah = 1 + 1;
    }
}
```